# Working Magic on Arguments - But only if they are Numbers (Javascript Algorithm)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, arguments

**Question**

Create a function that sums two arguments together. If only one argument is provided, then return a function that expects one argument and returns the sum.

For example, addTogether(2, 3) should return 5, and addTogether(2) should return a function.

Calling this returned function with a single argument will then return the sum:

var sumTwoAnd = addTogether(2);

sumTwoAnd(3) returns 5.

If either argument isn't a valid number, return undefined.

**What I Tried**

```js
function addTogether(a, b) {

if(typeof(a) !== 'number'){
return undefined;
}

if(arguments.length == 2){
 let tim = arguments[0] + arguments[1];
 if(!tim.isNaN){
   return tim;

 }
}

else if(arguments.length == 1){

  return function(a, c){

let result = c + a;
if(!result.isNaN){
  return result;
}

  }

}

}

addTogether(2,3);

console.log(addTogether(2)([3]))

console.log(addTogether(2),(3))
```

**The following Console.logs Fail**

addTogether(2)(3) should return 5.

addTogether(2, "3") should return undefined.

**addTogether(2)([3]) should return undefined.**

**What I would Like to Know**

1. How do you fix my code?
2. How would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to validate all the arguments as being numbers. You're doing that right initially, with `typeof a !== 'number'`, but you need to do that everywhere else too - both when checking `b`, if the second parameter is provided, and when returning the function, if the second parameter is not provided.

To return a function, just use `return (b) => { // logic }`:

```js
function addTogether(a, b) {
  if (typeof a !== 'number') {
    return;
  }
  if (arguments.length >= 2) {
    if (typeof b !== 'number') {
      return;
    }
    return a + b;
  }
  // then a is the only argument
  return (b) => {
    if (typeof b !== 'number') {
      return;
    }
    return a + b;
  };
}

console.log(addTogether(2, 3));
console.log(addTogether(2)(3));
console.log(addTogether('foo'));
```

Comment: The only thing I don't understand is how the return (b)=>{logic} works

Comment: Functions are first-class members in Javascript - you can define them as expressions, as done here at that point, and pass them around. The `b` is the argument, and what comes after the `{` is the function body.